# Google BigQuery Node library: how to stream data in batches?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-bigquery

I'm using the Google Cloud Node libraries for BigQuery. I'm using the [createQueryStream method](http://gle-cloud-node/#/docs/bigquery/0.9.6/bigquery?method=createQueryStream) to stream data from BigQuery:

```
var query = 'SELECT transfer_date, price, postcode FROM ';
query += '[table] ORDER BY transfer_date LIMIT 10000';
bigquery.createQueryStream(query)
  .on('error', console.error)
  .on('data', function(row) {
    console.log(row);
  })
  .on('end', function() {
    // All rows retrieved.
  });
```

This outputs each row individually to the console. However, I would like to update my application in batches, say every 10,000 results. So how do I amend the query to stream data in chunks of 10,000?

The [query method](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/bigquery/0.9.6/bigquery?method=query) has an `autoPaginate` option, but I don't understand how to use it.

Or do I need to write a function manually that fires each 10,000 rows? But that seems very inefficient.

Answer (score 4):

Bigquery node.js API takes care of the pagination automatically when you execute the query, you don't have to do anything.
The API method you are using is to **stream** result record **one** at a time. 
If you are only interested in processing results in batch and NOT in how pagination happens during each REST request then you might want to try:

```
    var rows = [];
    var batchSize = 10 * 1000;
    var counter = 0;
    var batchCounter = 0;
    var query = 'SELECT transfer_date, price, postcode FROM ';
    query += '[table] ORDER BY transfer_date';

    var bigquery = require('@google-cloud/bigquery')();
    bigquery.createQueryStream(query)
    .on('error', console.error)
    .on('data', function(row) {
        //Either use the stream record or keep pushing it to stack.
            if(counter < batchSize){
                rows.push(row);                      
                counter++;
            }else{
                counter=0;
                batchCounter++;
                //process the batch of records i.e., fire the custom event or send the content to down-stream applications etc.
                rows.forEach(function(row){console.log(row)});
                console.log('Completed batch no.:'+batchCounter);
                rows.clear;
            }
    })
    .on('end', function() {
        //If you want to process results only at the end.
        console.log('+++++End of the query results+++++'));
    });
```

*options* object in createQueryStream method is same as query method.
**autoPaginate** option is set to *true* by default.
From documents, Here is a [link](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/bigquery/0.8.0/bigquery?method=query)

P.S. You can always limit the total number of records in query stream by including LIMIT clause in the query.

Comment: Thanks. Won't that return a *maximum* of 10,000 rows in the request, though? I'd like to handle millions of rows, but fire an event in my client-side code each time 10,000 rows are available.

Comment: I have updated the answer. **maxResults** parameter controls how many records to be included in each page during pagination. I have ran a quick test and it appears you can only control total number of records in **createQueryStream** method using LIMIT clause in the query. **maxApiCalls** and **maxResults** only affect the internal pagination.